# Visual Studio Code 1.32 - it hangs on intelisense

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with version 1.32.2 but on earlier versions I saw this issue too and I have MacBook Pro 2018 2.6GHz . Sometimes when I'm writing code I'm switching between files with shortcut `CMD + P` and I found big issue that I need to wait 15-20 minutes or just restart Visual Studio Code. When I want to check intellisense I'm getting message

> Loading...

And at the top of file I see spinner for loading my intellisense. It's really annoying because I need to write everything from hand. Someone saw that issue too ?

I have tried to reinstall VSCode and Mojave and nothing worked for me.

[image]

**EDIT**

When i press TAB i cannot switch by default but at the bottom of VSCode I saw message and spinner

> Activating Extenstions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this extensions did that loading problem, I solved issue by uninstalling those extensions:

```
debugger-for-chrome
html-css-class-completion
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling "debugger-for-chrome" extension works for me.